# Postgresql querying records where the previous record already in completed status

Tags: sql, postgresql

based on the following data in the database:

[image]

i would like to query for all the records where status = null, but the status of the previous step_no is "done" group by the order.

appreciate some guidance on what sql can do so.

Comment: Hint : **lag** function

Comment: thx let me check on that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[lag()](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-window-function/postgresql-lag-function/)** function like below:

```
with cte as (
select 
*, 
lag(status,1) over ( order by "order", "step") "previous" 
from demo
)
select 
"order", 
step, 
status 
from cte where status is null and previous='done'
```

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/hjslHOoj)**